# userform using variable of a commandbutton

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, userform

I have a problem that I can not solve ... my problem is this:

I need to create a User Form that performs data search within 4 sheets, this data is the same only changing from year to year in the spreadsheets, but when I try to link my CommandBotton and use the variable in the error combo box ...

The business rule is as follows:

The User enters the employee's enrollment in this automatically pulls the data to the fields of the User Form, in case he wanted to change the worksheet he used the combo box to change between those worksheets and executing the same search but in different worksheets.

```html
Public plan As Worksheet

Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Sheets(ComboBox1.ListIndex + 1).Activate

End Sub

Sub UserForm_Initialize()

For Each plan In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

ComboBox1.AddItem plan.Name

Next plan

End Sub

Sub bnt1_Click()

   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(plan).Range("A:A")


Set c = .Find(textCp.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)

If Not c Is Nothing Then

c.Activate
textCp.Value = c.Value
textName.Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
textAd.Value = c.Offset(0, 2).Value
text60.Value = c.Offset(0, 65).Value
text60_20.Value = c.Offset(0, 66).Value
text100.Value = c.Offset(0, 67).Value
text100_20.Value = c.Offset(0, 68).Value
textAdc.Value = c.Offset(0, 69).Value
textAdcT.Value = c.Offset(0, 70).Value

End If
End With

End Sub

Sub btnSair_Click()

Unload FormPes

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `With plan.Range("A:A")`.

Here is how I would write the code.   I fell like `With c.EntireRow` would make it easier to identify which columns that you are referring to, as opposed to `c.Offset(0, 65).Value`.

```
Sub bnt1_Click()

   With plan.Range("A:A")
        Set c = .Find(textCp.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)

        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            With c.EntireRow
                textCp.Value = .Value
                textName.Value = .Range("B1").Value
                textAd.Value = .Range("C1").Value
                text60.Value = .Range("BN1").Value
                text60_20.Value = .Range("BO1").Value
                text100.Value = .Range("BP1").Value
                text100_20.Value = .Range("BQ1").Value
                textAdc.Value = .Range("BR1").Value
                textAdcT.Value = .Range("BS1").Value
            End With
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```